# My c shell script doesn't catch exit status 2, when tar failed

Tags: shell

I have the code below

```
ssh ${DESTSERVNAME} 'cd /export/home/path/to/dir; Today=`date +%Y%m%d`; tar -cvf file_name.tar *${Today}*.*; gzip file_name.tar'    
if [ $? != 0 ]    
then    
    echo "Something is wrong with connection to ${DESTSERVNAME} or $
```

{DAILY_DEST_DIR}. Please Check the $LOGF filei, connecttion to ${DESTSERVNAME} o
r files on ${DAILY_DEST_DIR},${NAME}.sh terminated abnormaly" | mailx -r emailadreess@tt.com -s "!!!Please read  a $LOGF and make appropriate action" emailaddress@tt.com
         exit 1
    fi

I don't understand why my if condition doesn't catch $? = 2
I am on AIX and it is a c shell , and also my email line is not working.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: But... that's not csh – `if [ … ]` (and `if <cmd>` in general) is definitely Bourne shell syntax.

Comment: OK, no difference. Why it is not working?

Comment: Let's say this way. tar message is "tar: *20170208*.*: No such file or directory", but it creates tar file anyway

Answer (score 0):

So in your remote command you're *telling* the shell to ignore the exit status. Remember the difference between `a; b` and `a && b`: the former runs "b" no matter whether "a" succeeds or fails, while the latter stops if "a" failed.

So what you're getting from `ssh` is the exit status of the *last* command executed, which is always gzip because the `;` separator doesn't care about the previous ones.

Instead, use something like `ssh $host "cd /foo && tar --foo && gzip foo.tar"`.